# Is there any benefit to using an obarray rather than a hash-table in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an Emacs Lisp program that needs to keep track of a set of strings, use them for completion and test other strings for membership in the set.  In most languages without a built-in `set` type, I would use a dictionary or hash table with a dummy `t` or `1` value for this, but it occurred to me that Elisp's `obarray` type could also serve the purpose, with `intern`, `intern-soft` and `unintern` taking the place of `puthash`, `gethash` and `remhash`.

(I know about the `cl-lib` functions which operate on lists as sets, but those are not particularly relevant for this problem, which only needs a set membership test).

Is there any advantage (in speed, memory usage or otherwise) in using an obarray rather than a hash table in a modern Emacs, or are obarrays other than the main symbol table more of a leftover from before Emacs Lisp had a separate hash-table type?

Comment: From what I've read. All you could do is intern and unintern values in a new obarray, but there is no way to access or modify values associated with the symbols.

Comment: That's not quite right -- you can use `symbol-value` and `set` as with normal symbols: `(let* ((o (make-vector 11 0)) (s (intern "s" o))) (set s 'value) (symbol-value s))` → `value`.  But in this case interning and uninterning would be sufficient anyway.

Comment: I suspect that an obarray may be less space-efficient than a hash-table for representing a set, since the hash-table wastes a single value slot per key, while the obarray wastes at least three, since each symbol has a value, function and plist slot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since both work, it's to a large extent a question of taste or performance.

In terms of memory usage (counted in words), an obarray uses 1 array of fixed size N plus one symbol per entry (of size 6), whereas a hash-table has a size that is more or less 5 per element plus a bit more.  So memorywise, it's a wash.

In terms of speed, I don't know anyone who has bothered to measure it, so it's probably not a big issue either.

IOW, it's a question of taste.  FWIW, I prefer hash tables which offer more options; obarrays are largely a historical accident in my view.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I was interested to learn that the memory usage is about the same, which I had not expected.